# Father-child and sales rollup

Tags: sql, rollup

I have table of employees and column called managedby.
I want to roll actual and target figures up from employee to lead to manager to director and etc.

```
create table
(
empid int
,Name varchar(255)
,actual decimal(38,2)
,target decimal(38,2)
,managedby int
)
```

and below is what have done so far:

```
    with emp(Period,Label,[name],Unit,Department,[Group],Division,Managed_By,Manager,Actual,Target) as
(
select 
a.DW_Time_key Period
,Label
,b.name
,b.Unit
,b.Department
,b.[Group]
,b.Division
,b.Managed_By
,b.Manager
,sum(a.Actual) Actual
,sum(a.Budget) Target
from 
KPI_EDW.dbo.Fact_ASO_SCORECARD a
,KPI_EDW.dbo.DIM_Employee b 
where
a.DW_EMPLOYEE_KEY = b.DW_EMPLOYEE_KEY 
and DW_KPI_KEY = 1008
and DW_Time_key = 200906
--and DW_Division_KEY = 1003
group by
a.DW_Time_key
,b.name
,b.Unit
,b.Department
,b.[Group]
,b.Division 
,b.Managed_By
,b.Manager
,b.Label
)
,CTE (Label,[Name],[Manager], Managed_By,Actual,Target,[level]) as
(
select cast(Label as int) Label,[Name],[Manager], null,Actual,Target,0
from emp
where cast(Label as int) = '582'

union all

select 
cast(h2.Label as int) Label
,h2.[Name]
,h2.[Manager]
,cast(h2.Managed_By as int) Managed_By 
,h2.Actual
,h2.Target
,[level] + 1
from emp h2
inner join cte
on cast(h2.Managed_By as int) = cast(cte.Label as int)
)


select *
from cte
order by [level]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify what your exact question is?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a way to sum the actual and target values for a list of all the employees under a certain manager as well as everyone under them, and so on, to get the totals for an entire branch. Is that correct? I wrote a recursive function to do that in SQL Server. I can post it if I am understanding the problem correctly.

Here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ListStaff] (@Supv int) 
--Recursively returns tree of managed staff
--select * from ListStaff(5)
RETURNS @result TABLE
    (empid int ,
    Name varchar(26),
    managedby int,
    SupvName varchar(26),
    NestLev int 
 )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @empid int, @Name char(26), @managedby int, @SupvName char(26)

    SELECT @SupvName = supv.Name, @managedby = emp.managedby, @Name = emp.Name
    FROM yourTable emp LEFT JOIN yourTable supv
    ON emp.managedby = supv.empid
    WHERE emp.empid = @Supv
    -----------------------
      INSERT INTO @result
      VALUES (@Supv, @Name, @managedby, @SupvName, @@NESTLEVEL)
    -----------------------
    SET @empid = (SELECT MIN(emp.empid)     
    FROM yourTable emp LEFT JOIN yourTable supv
    ON emp.managedby = supv.empid
    WHERE emp.managedby = @Supv)

    WHILE @empid IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @@NESTLEVEL < 32
        IF @empid <> @Supv
        INSERT INTO @result
        SELECT * FROM ListStaff(@empid)

        SET @empid = (SELECT MIN(emp.empid) 
        FROM yourTable emp LEFT JOIN yourTable supv
        ON emp.managedby = supv.empid
        WHERE emp.managedby = @Supv AND emp.empid > @empid)
    END
RETURN
END

/* This draws the organizartion chart in a formatted tree.

select CONVERT(CHAR(1),nestLev) + REPLICATE('-', nestLev * 4 - 4) + Name + ' is supervised by ' + SupvName
FROM ListStaff(@bossid)

*/

/* link the results back to your table to get values like this:
SELECT *
FROM ListStaff(5) supv
INNER JOIN yourTable
ON supv.empid = yourTable.empid
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for the response. Yes I will be expecting the SQL recursive function.. Many Thanks